# URLs for SEO - which is better?

Tags: seo

I think my CMS might force me to have URLs that look like these:

- `domain.com/products/new-products/`
- `domain.com/products/used-products/`

Instead of:

- `domain.com/new-products/`
- `domain.com/used-products/`

Assume that I was trying to optimize for "new products" and "used products". **Will having the URLs my CMS might be forcing on me be bad for SEO?** I could do something like this:

- `domain.com/products/new/`
- `domain.com/products/used/`

(but I don't think these are optimizing for "new products" and "used product" due to the ordering of the key words)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is perfectly valid to use your urls.

A SEO friendly url might look something like this:
http://store.example.com/topics/subtopics/descriptive-produkt-name#top

VS

http://store.example.com/index.php?produkt=1234&sort=price&print=1

Comment: But if I am trying to optimize for "new products" and my URL is "/products/new/", that's not optimal, is it?

Comment: That is correct, your url won't be that descriptive. Much better with the new-products name :)